# Setting up a quiz in php that accepts slightly wrong answers

Tags: php, html

So recently I was looking into PHP and I have managed to set up a little quiz making use of it. The question that I have is how would I make the quiz accept slightly spelt wrong answers? For example if my quiz asked what was the capital of Alabama and someone spelt Montgomery slightly wrong how would I allow it to still count it as right? I would like to do this for all of the questions that my quiz ask and I hope I have worded my question well enough, if not let me know. Here is the code I am currently using, and yes it is set up into three files as I find having it in one file complicated and I please would like answers referring to the multiple files I have, I would not like an example of all of the php code on one page if possible. Code:

Code for listing the states and capitals, not full list but example:

```
<?php
$states = Array();
$capitals = Array();
$states[]="Alabama";
$capitals[]="Montgomery";
$states[]="Alaska";
$capitals[]="Juneau";
$states[]="Arizona";
$capitals[]="Phoenix";
$states[]="Arkansas";
$capitals[]="Little Rock";
$states[]="California";
$capitals[]="Sacramento";
$states[]="Colorado";
$capitals[]="Denver";
$states[]="Connecticut";
$capitals[]="Hartford";
$states[]="Delaware";
....etc
   ?>
```

The actual main code for the base of the quiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>State capital quiz: ask</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>State Capital Quiz </h1><p>
<?php
$saywhich=@$_GET['saywhich'];
if ($saywhich){
  include("statecapitals.php");
  $which=$_GET['which'];
  $choice=rand(0, sizeOf($states)-1);
   if ($which=='state') {
     $state = $states[$choice];
     print("What is the capital of $state?<br>");
     print("<form action='statecapquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
     print("<input type='text' name='capital'><br>\n");
     print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
     print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
     print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
     print("</form>\n");
   }   
else   {
     $capital = $capitals[$choice];
     print("$capital is the capital of which state?<br>");
     print("<form action='statecapquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
     print("<input type='text' name='state'><br>\n");
     print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
     print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
     print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
     print("</form>\n");
   }
}
else {
print("Choose form of question: do you want to be given the state or     the capital?<br>");
print("<form action='statecapquizask.php' method='get'>\n");
print("Ask <input type='radio' name='which' value='state'>State");
print(" <input type='radio' name='which' value='capital'>Capital\n");
print("<input type='hidden' name='saywhich' value='true'>\n");
print("<input type='submit' value='Submit choice'>");
print("</form>");
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Code for checking if the answers are correct:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>State capitals quiz: check</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>State Capital Quiz </h1><p>
<?php
include('statecapitals.php');
$choice=$_GET['choice'];
$state=@$_GET['state'];
$capital=@$_GET['capital'];
$which=$_GET['which'];
$correctstate=$states[$choice];
$correctcapital=$capitals[$choice];
if ($which=='state') {
    if ($capital == $correctcapital) {
       print("Correct! $correctcapital is the capital of      $correctstate!");
       print("<p><a href='statecapquizask.php'>Play again </a>");
      }   
    else {
       print("WRONG!<p>\n");
       print("<a href='statecapquizask.php'>New turn </a><p>\n");
       print("OR try again: What is the capital of $correctstate?<br>");
      print("<form action='statecapquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
      print("<input type='text' name='capital'><br>\n");
      print("<input type='hidden' name='state' value=$state>\n");
      print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
      print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
      print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
      print("</form>\n");
    }  }
else {
 if ($state == $correctstate) {
       print("Correct! The capital of $correctstate is     $correctcapital!");
       $saywhich='false';
       print("<p><a href='statecapquizask.php'>Play again </a>");
       }
   else {
print("WRONG!<p>\n");
       print("<a href='statecapquizask.php'>New turn </a><p>\n");
      print("OR try again: $correctcapital is the capital of what state?<br>");
     print("<form action='statecapquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
print("<input type='text' name='state'><br>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='capital' value=$capital>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
 print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
 print("</form>\n");
}  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would consider the functions: similar_text, levenshtein,soundex

Comment: You'll have to use something fuzzy like soundex.  I would also suggest using associative arrays for states/capitals, ie, `$capital['Alabama'] = 'Montgomery';`. This would ensure that your list doesn't mysteriously get off by one.

Comment: @TimMorton Yes I actually really should thanks for the suggestion and may you or smith give a quick explanation of how I would implement any of these things I understand the use but I don't understand how to implement something like this so then my program can check and still accept it

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php

Comment: I've never used soundex, so the link is my best advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you've had enough time to play around with this on your own, because that's how you learn.

If you've taken the time to hack this on your own, then I submit this script for anything you might glean from it. I took your scenario and wrote a procedural script to try it out; I was curious about `soundex()`. Yes, this is a one-pager... Not at all the way I would normally do things, as I would use classes so that it is unit testable.

This uses the convention of PHP on the top; HTML on the bottom.  This helps enforce separation of logic and presentation.

The html might or might not work; it is untested.

FWIW, I discovered that `soundex` is ***very, very, very*** forgiving! So instead, I used `metaphone`.

```
<?php

// initialize all variables

$get = $_GET; // this was done for testing and I'm too lazy to replace it ;)

$success = false;
$choose_which = true;
$supplied_term = '';
$which = '';
$checked_answer = false;
$answer_array = array();

// state => capital
$states = array(
  'Alabama'     => 'Montgomery',
  'Alaska'      => 'Juneau',
  'Arizona'     => 'Phoenix',
  'Arkansas'    => 'Little Rock',
  'California'  => 'Sacremento',
  // ... etc
  );

// capital => state
$capitals = array_flip($states);


function get_random($stateOrCapital) {

  $indexed_list = array_keys($stateOrCapital);
  $random_index = (rand(0, sizeOf($indexed_list)-1));
  return $indexed_list[$random_index];
}

function check_answer($submitted,$correct) {
  //return (soundex($submitted) == soundex($correct)); // too forgiving
  return (metaphone($submitted) == metaphone($correct));
}


// are we checking state or capital?  Decouple GET input, choose which list to use for answers
if( array_key_exists('which', $get)) {

  // don't show radio buttons
  $choose_which = false;

  switch($get['which']) {
    case 'capital':
      $which = 'capital';
      $answer_array = $capitals;
      break;

    default:
      $which = 'state';
      $answer_array = $states;

  }
} 


// show question?
if($choose_which == false) {

  $supplied_term = get_random($answer_array);

}

// check answer?
if( array_key_exists('check_answer', $get)) {

  $supplied_term = htmlentities($get['supplied_term']);
  $correct_answer = $answer_array[$supplied_term];
  $success = check_answer($get['answer'],$correct_answer);
  $checked_answer = true;


}

// default is to ask which type of question
// everything below could be separated into a view.

?><html>
<head>
<title>State capital quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>State Capital Quiz </h1>

  <?php if($checked_answer): ?>
    <?php if($success): ?>
      <h2>CORRECT</h2>
    <?php else: ?>
      <h2>Sorry, try again...</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if($choose_which || $success): ?>
    <h2>Which do you wish to answer?</h2>
    <form action='' method="get">
      <div><label>Capital <input type='radio' name='which' value='capital' /></label></div>
      <div><label>State <input type='radio' name='which' value='state' /></label></div>
      <div><input type='submit' /></div>
    </form>

  <?php else: ?>
    <p>What is the matching state or capital for <?= $supplied_term ?></p>

    <form action='' method='get'>
      <input type='hidden' name='check_answer' value='true'>
      <input type='hidden' name='which' value='<?= $which ?>'>
      <input type='hidden' name='supplied_term' value='<?= $supplied_term ?>'>

      <input type='text' name='answer'><br>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>
    </form>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am unsure to put you answer as correct. I salute you for finding megaphone, I was playing with soundex and have it set up and working however as you stated it is bad actually. Metaphone has this much more realistic forgiveness and all I needed to do was replace the word soundex with methane everything else still gets set up the same way. I am unsure to mark this correct as I do not know of your code works although your suggestion of metaphone is the best yet

Comment: Glad to see it was helpful